# Compiler Warning Passing array of structs (itself member of struct) to Function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I have the following structs defined - a struct of co-ordinates is itself a member of a parent struct

```
typedef struct _coord {
    double x;   // time axis - seconds rather than samples
    double y;
}   t_coord;

typedef struct _algosc {                    
    t_coord coords[COORD_COUNT];        
    //... struct continues beyond this but...
}   t_algosc;
```

I create a pointer to the parent struct and then allocate memory. object_alloc is a malloc type function specific to the API (MAX5) defined elsewhere. This is all working so I'm not including details.

```
static t_class *algosc_class;   // pointer to the class of this object

    t_algosc *x = object_alloc(algosc_class)
```

This is the declaration for the function to which I wish to pass the array of coord structs

```
    void    au_update_coords(t_coord (*coord)[])
```

I pass the array to the function as follows,

```
au_update_coords(x->coords);
```

it all works fine, but I get compiler warnings

```
1>db.algosc~.c(363): warning C4047: 'function' : 't_coord (*)[]' differs in levels of indirection from 't_coord [4]'
1>db.algosc~.c(363): warning C4024: 'au_update_coords' : different types for formal and actual parameter 1
```

I can't work out the correct way to pass the struct. Can anyone help. Also just for my edification, what sort of issues do I risk leaving it as it is?

Comment: Your example declaration takes seven parameters, but you invoke the function with only one parameter. I assume this results from an incomplete pass at removing unnecessary code for your question? Please correct it.

Comment: Arrays decays naturally to pointers, so not need to pass a pointer to an array, just pass the array itself (which you do now), which of course have to be reflected in the function argument declaration (i.e. drop the pointer declaration).

Comment: Thanks Joachim - very clear, if that had been posted as an answer I'd have picked it as the answer.

Comment: this line: 'void    au_update_coords(t_coord (*coord)[])' is passing an array of pointers to t_coord types.  I suspect that is not what you want to actually do.  suggest: 'void    au_update_coords(t_coord  *coord)'  You might want to pass a second parameter that indicates the number of entries in the coord array

Comment: I think you're wrong there - [] binds more strongly than * so (*x)[] is a pointer to an array - *x[] is an array of pointers - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_array_of_pointers.htm

Comment: @user3629249: You are mistaken. C declarations can be hard to read; they have to be read inside-out in a confusing spiral fashion. `t (*x)[]` means that `(*x)` has type `t ...[]`. One very helpful tool for sanity-checking your interpretation is [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org/); see [its explanation for `struct _coord (*coord)[]`](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=struct+_coord+%28*coord%29[]).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a pointer to the array, so you need to take the address of your array to make it a pointer to an array, this

```
au_update_coords(x->coords, otherArguments ...);
```

should become

```
au_update_coords(&x->coords, otherArguments ...);
```

But you don't need that. If you worry about the function not altering the array in place stop worrying about it will, you need to change the function signature from

```
void    au_update_coords(t_coord (*coord)[], otherArguments ...)
```

to

```
void    au_update_coords(t_coord *coord, otherArguments ...)
```

and pass the array directly as in

```
au_update_coords(x->coords, otherArguments ...);
```

of course, you will probably need to fix the `au_update_coords()` function wherever you access the array.

Comment: `x->coords` is not a variable-length array, it has fixed dimension `COORD_COUNT`.(Structs cannot contain VLA anyway)

Comment: @iharob no it isn't; pointer to VLA looks like `T (*ptr)[n]`.  That is different to `T (*ptr)[]` which is pointer to incomplete array type.

Comment: Thanks matt - I hadn't spotted that detail. Good point. 
Iharob, if you can remove that reference to VLA I'll keep this as selected answer, otherwise this is misleading to anyone else who finds it..